FCMServerError: FCM server is temporarily unavailable (pyFCM)
I'm using FCM to send push notifications to android devices but I'm experiencing this error:
FCMServerError: FCM server is temporarily unavailable
The metrics dashboard shows that no notifications have been sent since September 4, 2024; and I haven't changed anything in the code.

Has anyone else experienced this error or know what it is due to?
PD: I'm using pyFCM to send this push notifications.
Any advice? Do you recommend some other service to send push notification to android devices?
I searched for any deprecation or something like that but I didn't find anything.

Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not production support.  If you're having problems with Firebase services, check the status dashboard first, then contact Firebase support directly.  Stack Overflow is also not for asking for product recommendations.

Any update on this? I have the same issue

We experienced the same issue starting on September 4th.
This issue is probably caused by the deprecation of FCM legacy APIs for HTTP and XMPP.
Shutdown has began on July 22nd.
You will need to update PyFCM to v.2.x that added support to the new HTTP v1.
